# Documentation first topic layout (style) is messed up

Tags: bug, documentation, design

I am trying SO documentation at work (Firefox ESR 38.5.0) and the first topics of each tag in documentation is messed up:

[image]

I did not have this problem when browsing SO documentation at home (latest version of Firefox).

---

The problem may be that the `div` below (first `div` in `.mainbar`) has a height of `0` in the inspector, probably due to the two floating elements inside.

```
<div>
    <h2 class="topic-list-count">3 Topics</h2>
    <div id="" class="subtabs"></div>
</div>
<div class="topics">
```

Comment: I'm having the same experience at my work with Firefox 38.1. ESR